# ansible: get network IP from a host

Tags: variables, ansible

I am using ansible to set up a NFS server on linux machine. I would like to give access to to the /data_to_share directory present on NFS server to all machines sharing the same LAN. This is why I would like to export the NFS at:

```
/data_to_share      192.168.0.0/24(rw)
```

With ansible I can get the IP address of the NFS host, using the variable:

```
{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
```

That would return `192.168.0.13`. Is there a variable for the network IP, i.e.`192.168.0.0`, or some other way to get there? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the relevant build-in ansible variables that I needed running an ad-hoc action:

```
ansible -m setup hostname
```

Those are:

```
ansible_default_ipv4.network
ansible_default_ipv4.netmask
```

I can build the export path using

```
"{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}/{{ansible_default_ipv4.netmask}}"
```

that renders to:
    192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0